# ARM v8 Assembly Language Program

Tags: assembly, arm, armv8

Hello I am trying to create a program in assembly that :

read an integer and a character from the keyboard and make some calculations. The program is about water consumption. In case of wrong input the program should print an error message and then terminate. For example if i give first the integer and is negative the program should print error and terminate.

Although, it always print error messages and i need some help... here is my code if someone can help please

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0HbcT5zQEuGaEYtNUhxYk9GcE0/view?usp=sharing

.Question_typos:

.string "Plese Enter type of use (o/O e/E b/B) :"

.Question_kivika:
    .string "Please Enter the amount of water you have used :"

.ScanfStr:
    .string "%c"

.ScanfStr2:
    .string "%d"

.Reply:
    .string "The result is: %d\n"

.Reply_error:
    .string "Invalid data input.\n"
    .text
    .align  2
    .global main

main:

.LFB0:

```
stp x29, x30, [sp, -32]!

add x29, sp, 0

adrp    x0, .Question_kivika
add x0, x0, :lo12:.Question_kivika
bl  printf
add x1, x29, 28
adrp    x0, .ScanfStr2
add x0, x0, :lo12:.ScanfStr2
bl  scanf
ldr x21, [x29, 28]  

cmp     x21, xzr
b.mi    error_msg

adrp    x0, .Question_typos
add x0, x0, :lo12:.Question_typos
bl  printf
add x1, x29, 28
adrp    x0, .ScanfStr
add x0, x0, :lo12:.ScanfStr
bl  scanf
ldr x20, [x29, 28]  

bl  compute_bill    
mov     x21, x22
b   result
```

compute_bill:

```
mov x22, 0  

cmp x20, 'o'
b.eq    house
cmp x20, 'O'
b.eq    house
cmp x20, 'e'
b.eq    prof
cmp x20, 'E'
b.eq    prof
cmp x20, 'b'
b.eq    factory
cmp x20, 'B'
b.eq    factory
ret

house:
    mov x23, 5
    mov     x24, 10
    smaddl  x22, w23, w21, x24      
    ret

prof:
    mov x23, 3
    mov x24, 1000
    smaddl  x22, w23, w21, x24
    ret

factory:
    mov x23, 1
    mov x24, 3000
    smaddl  x22, w23, w21, x24
    ret
```

result:
    mov     x1,x21
    adrp    x0, .Reply
    add x0, x0, :lo12:.Reply
    bl  printf
    nop
    ldp x29, x30, [sp], 32
    ret

error msg:
    adrp    x0, .Reply_error
    add x0, x0, :lo12:.Reply_error 
    bl  printf
    nop
    ldp x29, x30, [sp], 32
    ret

picture of execution

https://i.stack.imgur.com/krmwq.jpg

Comment: We need more info - for example, what does it do right, what does it do wrong, and any error messages while the latter.  In [help] search for 'how to ask'

Comment: Don't spam tags. This is not related to C!

Comment: i updated the question with more information. Thank you !